# Bcrypt Returing [Object Promise] or Promise { <pending> } after Hashing a Code

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, bcrypt

I am creating an account signup system for a React app. I am having an issue when trying to hash a password using `Bcrypt`. My function I use to hash a password is here:

```
async function genPassword(password) {
  let hashpass = bcrypt.hash(String(password), 9)
  return hashpass
}
```

I call this code later during an SQL call here:

```
const sql = "INSERT INTO USER (userFName, UserLName, userPhone, IsDelete, userEmail, userPassword) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);" 
      db.query(sql, [fname, lname, phone, 0, email, String(genPassword(password))], (err, data, fields, ) => { 
//Code to follow omitted
```

I got this to upload to my database, but got this value in mySQL workbench for the password: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbjVo.png)

As you can see, I get an `[Object Promise]` instead of the hash. Similarly, I get  `Promise { <pending> }`
when I console.log this.

Can anyone see what I may have done incorrectly here? When I hash this in a separate file using bcrypt this works fine, so I am quite confused as to where I have made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use this:

```
const generatePassword = async (password) => {
 return await new Promise((res, rej) => {
  // Your hash logic 
  bcrypt.hash(password, 10, (err, hash) => {
    if (err) rej(err);
    res(hash);
   });
 });
};
```

When calling it:

```
 const password = await generatePassword('1234');
```

The hash method returns a promise so
If you don't want to change your code just use `async/await` or `then` to resolve the promise value.

Comment: This did not seem to work. While the code runs just fine, I get the same result.

Comment: You should resolve the promise value before calling `db.query` Could you provide all the code snippet where you call `genPassword`?